# Как мне повернуть камеру в Unity точно без лишних поворотов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как мне повернуть камеру в Unity точно без лишних поворотов

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("z"))
        {
            transform.Translate(7, 2, 0);
            transform.Rotate(9, 271, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("x"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-1, 0, 0);
            transform.Rotate(0, 271, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит "точно"? И какие лишние повороты вы совершаете?

Comment: Я нажимаю на кнопку и он вращается пока не отпущу
Мне нужно чтоб я нажал на кнопку и он переместился на координаты и далше не перемещался

Comment: Ну так у вас стоит условие "пока нажата клавиша, вращай". Вам же нужно отлавливать событие KeyUp или KeyDown. С Unity не знаком, так что точнее не подскажу